# Show loader in Material-UI CardMedia

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to show loader in CardMedia when image is not loaded yet but its not working. If I place loader in CardText then the page is working and a loader is shown. What's wrong with my code or is there a solution to show loader in card media before image loads?

[image: Screenshot for your ref]

I am using material-ui v0 version.

Here is my code

Loader:

```
renderLoading(){
return (
  <RefreshIndicator
    size={40}
    left={10}
    top={0}
    status="loading"
    style={{marginLeft: '50%', display: 'inline-block', position: 'relative'}}
/>
)
}
```

Card:

```
<CardMedia overlay={<CardTitle title={this.props.userName} subtitle="Your cover photo" />}>
   {this.props.coverPhotoLoading && this.renderLoading()} //this isn't working 
   {coverPhoto ? <img src={coverPhoto} width="100%" height="400px"/> :
      <img src="" alt="This user cover photo is not set" width="100%" height="400px"/>}

</CardMedia>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `this.props.coverPhotoLoading` is defined as you expect? I tried this example using your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes this.props.coverPhotoLoading is defined. I am able to see loader if I place this in CardText but the same is not working in CardMedia.

Comment: I realize that the difference between my code and yours is that I'm either showing the loader or the photo. It looks to me like you're trying to show both the loader and an empty image at the same time. That might be why it's not working. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I am able to see loader now after removing empty image.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've added this as an answer, feel free to accept it if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you're trying to display both the `<RefreshIndicator />` and an empty `<img/>` at the same time.

Consider doing something like the following:

```
<CardMedia overlay={<CardTitle title={this.props.userName} subtitle="Your cover photo" />}>
   {!this.props.coverPhotoLoading && coverPhoto ?
    <img src={coverPhoto} width="100%" height="400px"/> :
    this.renderLoading()}
</CardMedia>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please upvote my question if you feel it’s valid.